# Azure Data Studio, Error: Failed to Expand Node

Tags: postgresql, azure-data-studio

Connecting to Postgres server is successful, but by clicking on `Databases` to expand database folder, the Error: Failed to expand node will be raised.

[image]

- Extension version: 0.2.7
- Azure Data Studio version: azuredatastudio 1.43.0

I'm using PostgreSQL 15.2 installed on Ubuntu server.

[image]

I do this linked solution:

[Azure Data Studio Failed to Expand Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74376366/azure-data-studio-failed-to-expand-node)

but still got the error on expanding 'Indexes' folder!

is there any general and official solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to connect the Azure Postgres SQL with Azure Data studio and able to access the database node and other nodes in it.

[image]

**Here I used all the latest versions try with updating it:**

- Extension version: v0.3.1
- Azure Data Studio version: azuredatastudio 1.44.0

You can also see this similar GitHub issue raised [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio-postgresql/issues/333).

Also check if your firewall is allowing ADS to connect successfully to the Azure Postgres SQL.

Comment: Yes it's been fixed, Thanks.